# how to store mysql password and ... out my my source code in a seperated file?

Tags: mysql, database, file, syntax, passwords

i just want to store my database passwords and... to have a secure connection to mysql db in my website.

here is my code:

```
function mysqli_connet()
{
    $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysamplepassword");
    if (!$this->connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("mydb",$this->connection);
}
```

i know that i shoud write it to a file and lock it's access butwhat that i don't know is how is the syntax in the file. i mean i don't know how to start and end it and what's the syntax in the file? i just want an example or sth
i wanna know how shoud i change my code to be secure
the second question is that should i include that file in mydatabase.php file?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Don't put any source code other than what's strictly necessary to run your site in the web root. Everything else should be included as required from a different location. Most frameworks have a stub `index.php` and that's it apart from static assets.